# Reinstall xampp

Tags: database, xampp

Im using a mac.  Xampp stopped working after the latest update 10.6.8 and I think it may be a direct result of the update.  Anyway, Id like to reinstall xampp however i didnt backup my database and i cant get into localhost/phpmyadmin to import it.  Is there anyway I can backup my database another way and reinstall xampp?  or is there another problem as to why the pages dont load.

I get this error when i go to localhost/phpmyadmin:   The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

When you use XAMPP, it automatically freezes all the other database. If you are using mysql, you can backup them either using

**1.mysqladmin tool** (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) 
 directly login as the admin and select the databases that you need and backup.

or

**2.using command line** (manual backup): 
 goto mysql/bin and then follow this tutorial: http://linux.byexamples.com/archivesc/90/backup-and-restore-mysql-database/

Comment: what do you mean by xampp freezes other databases?

Comment: I have tried XAMPP for my CMS (Joomla) and was using a database (lets say XAMPPDB). I also had other databases(which are not part of CMS) as well. But, when I tried in mysql query browser, I couldn't view any of the other db's. So, try either of the above two solns. and if you feel the answer is correct, accept it as answer. 
Cheers.

Comment: freeze ==> not letting the user to view/operate with other db

Comment: i dont think you understand the question.  I only have one database.  Im wondering why after I updated my mac xampp stopped working.

Comment: I answered only for 

" Is there anyway I can backup my database another way"

I really don't have idea about XAMMP problem. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall xampp, the databases (in var/mysql) and the htdocs folders are not normally deleted by the uninstall wizard. When you reinstall xampp, those existing folders will be used. It's also a good idea to back up those folders directly to reduce the risk of loss.